# Overleaf same tex file, different output

Tags: overleaf

I know it sounds weird, but it actually happens on my end.

I copied one overleaf project (created several month before) to a new one, so the content should be exactly same.

I compiled those two documents, it returned with pdf with slight variations.

For the old project, this is the end of first line and second line of title, [image]

For the newly copied project, word "communities"  went to the second line.

For other parts, this situation happens a few times.

What might be the cause? I diff-check all tex files and format files in those two projects, and it is exactly the same.

Really confused.

Comment: it may be possible that some packages have updated. also check that you are using the same TeX engine.

Comment: @plante, thanks, problem solved now. Overleaf defaults my newly copied project to the 2021 tex engine, while my old one is using the  2020 tex engine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar to the comment from user `plante`: Make sure that you use the same `TeX Live Version` and `Compiler`, see screenshots.

1. [image]
2. [image: List item]